# Session cookies and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

In my asp.net aplication i used such settings in web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" 
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
              stateNetworkTimeout="10" 
              sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
              sqlCommandTimeout="30" customProvider="" cookieless="UseCookies" 
              cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" 
              timeout="120" 
              allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" 
              regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
              partitionResolverType="" 
              useHostingIdentity="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

and

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" 
         defaultUrl="Default.aspx" 
         cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

but sometimes session behaviour stand strange

Users get `http://my.appl.com/S(DGsdgfg453dsgfsdgsdgsd)/mypage.html`
where `S(DGsdgfg453dsgfsdgsdgsd)` key for session for one user, but get him all users. As if `UseCookies = false.`

I restart applicaition and some time it work good. Then again.

What problem with my application?

Comment: The value for "cookieless" in the `<sessionState>` node is either 'true' or 'false', not 'UseCookies'.

Comment: not only http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx

Comment: and i used "false" without good result

Comment: I did check the docs, but apparently just the v1.1 version (and from v2.0 onward 'UseCookies' is supported). My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason was the memory is full. I kept a big serialized object in the Session.

I added in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Session.Clear(); //?
Session.Abandon();
}
```

and the problem disappeared.